# Get Fluent Nhibernate to not use parameters

Tags: sql, nhibernate, parameters

.Where(x => !x.Rated)
This creates sql that looks like:
not (cdrcalltmp0_.Rated=1)

Our dba says I have to remove the not for some filtered index to work.

.Where(x => x.Rated == false)
This creates sql that looks like:
cdrcalltmp0_.Rated=@p2 order by cdrcalltmp0_.Created asc'

This doesn't work because of the parameter.

He would like this sql:
cdrcalltmp0_.Rated=0 order by cdrcalltmp0_.Created asc'

Is it possible to make nhibernate not use parameters?
So that a filtered index works.

Comment: "This doesn't work because of the parameter." why doesn't that work?

Comment: agree, what the prob with "This doesn't work because of the parameter."

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea why the index would not work with parameters. I'm guessing it should.

Answer (score 0):

**Preface:**
The following answer is assuming you are using SQL Server 2008. If you are not, then it is quite possible that the database technology in question does not support indexes when using the NOT operator. So, if your using SQL Server 2008...

Your DBA doesn't know what he's talking about.

The following syntax

```
NOT ( SomeTableAlias.SomeTableColumn = 1 )
```

will **absolutely** be understood by the SQL Server Query Analyzer. I've got queries from NHibernate that look exactly like the above syntax and they are indeed using the proper indexes.

And to answer your question, no. NHibernate always uses parameters when it creates the SQL for you. Parameterized queries are extremely common place, even when using traditional ADO.NET yourself.

The only way to get NHibernate to not use parameters is if you supply the SQL it needs to execute yourself using the session.CreateSQLQuery() method.

At any rate, the above line you posted:

```
Where(x => x.Rated == false) This creates sql that looks like: cdrcalltmp0_.Rated=@p2 order by cdrcalltmp0_.Created asc'
```

is completely valid. When SQL Server receives the parameterized query, it will use whatever index is on your Rated column.

If your DBA still doubts you, tell him to run the query in Sql Server Management Studio with the "Display Estimated Execution Plan" feature on. That will prove that the query is using the index.

Comment: Don't be too sure about that. SQL Server 2000 doesn't even use an index for a clear `WHERE SomeBitColumn = 1`, because it interprets it as `WHERE CAST(SomeBitColumn AS INT) = 1` rather than `WHERE SomeBitColumn = CAST(1 AS BIT)`. I know that's been improved since, but it heavily depends on the exact version of SQL Server used. The question doesn't even clearly specify SQL Server is used at all rather than some other database engine (but admittedly the syntax does look like it).

Comment: @hvd Good point. I'll update my answer to preface that the statements I'm making are true for SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Update: It's a filtered index. Sometimes nhibernate doesn't use parameters. The first example in my orig question doesn't use parameters for some reason